# find and delete files of a certain type inside a tar.gz file

Tags: linux, unix, tar, gzip, grep

Is there a way to not only **find** but also **delete** any `.gz` files inside a `.tar.gz` file? I found [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34008/find-a-file-within-a-tar-gz-archive) but I wouldn't know how to modify it to make it able to delete found files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update compressed tar-files. So as long as you have a tar.gz file there is no way except unpacking, deleting and then repacking.

You could un-gzip the file though. After that there is a *--delete*-Flag you can use.